# How to create a multiindex dataframe that is sorted according to group size?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-index

I do have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IDs': list('abcdefgh'),
    'Val': [
        'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'abc', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'
    ]
})

  IDs  Val
0   a  foo
1   b  bar
2   c  foo
3   d  abc
4   e  bar
5   f  bar
6   g  foo
7   h  foo
```

I now want to get an output like this:

```
Val IDs           
foo a            
    c            
    g            
    h            
bar b            
    e            
    f            
abc d
```

So, it is the index of a multiindex dataframe which is ordered accoring to the `size` of each group in `Val`.

I currently do it like this:

```
df['groupsize'] = df.groupby('Val')['IDs'].transform('size')

df = (
    df.sort_values(['groupsize', 'Val', 'IDs'], ascending=[False, True, True])
      .drop('groupsize', axis=1)
      .set_index(['Val', 'IDs'])
)

df.to_excel('example.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

which gives the desired output.

Is there a way to achieve the same output but without creating this intermediate column `groupsize` which is dropped later anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `value_counts`

```
df.set_index('Val').loc[df.Val.value_counts().index]

Out[44]:
    IDs
Val
foo   a
foo   c
foo   g
foo   h
bar   b
bar   e
bar   f
abc   d
```

---

If you need multiindex, just chain addition `set_index` with `append=True`

```
df.set_index('Val').loc[df.Val.value_counts().index].set_index('IDs', append=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argsort` and `iloc` to avoid the verbose `sort_values`

```
s = np.argsort(-df.groupby('Val')['IDs'].transform('size'))

df.iloc[s].set_index(['Val', 'IDs'])
```

---

```
Val IDs
foo a
    c
    g
    h
bar b
    e
    f
abc d
```